# Compiling $(this) as $(_this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a problem with TypeScript replacing `$(this)` with `$(_this)` and breaking the code, because `test` refers to `window`.

```
$(".class").click(() => {
    var test = $(this);
    console.log(test);
});
```

compiles to

```
$(".class").click(function () {
    var test = $(_this);
    console.log(test);
});
```

Comment: that's because of the arrow function which needs to save the scope. In the compiled version, just before what you included there should be a `_this = this`. If you compile for `ES6` it should then keep the arrow function notation which will then won't need the `_this`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to capture the lexical `this`, don't use an arrow function. Just use a regular function expression:

```
$(".class").click(function () {
    var test = $(this);
    console.log(test);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that arrow changes scope

Comment: @David8 It's the opposite of that. The fat arrow doesn't change the scope, a regular function does.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use fat arrow function.

```
$(".class").click(function() {
    var test = $(this);
    console.log(test);
});
```